# How to log only errors with winston module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I have an application running on Node.js (server side) and I would like to only log errors based on an environment variable (For example : log_level=error node api.js) so this only logs errors on the console.

I have a log.js file that uses winston library

```
var fs = require("fs"),
  mkdirp = require("mkdirp"),
  path = require("path"),
  winston = require("winston");
  //const env = process.env.node_env || "development";

var filename = path.join(__dirname, "../app-debug.log");

//
// Remove the file, ignoring any errors
//
try {
  fs.unlinkSync(filename);
} catch (ex) {}

var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
  levels: {
    trace: 0,
    input: 1,
    verbose: 2,
    error: 3,
    debug: 4,
    info: 5,
    data: 6,
    help: 7,
    warn: 8
  },
  colors: {
    trace: "magenta",
    input: "grey",
    verbose: "cyan",
    prompt: "red",
    error: "blue",
    info: "green",
    data: "grey",
    help: "cyan",
    warn: "yellow"
  },
  transports: [
    new(winston.transports.Console)({
      prettyPrint: true,
      colorize: true,
      silent: false,
      timestamp: true,
      level: "error"
    }),
    new(winston.transports.File)({
      filename: filename
    })
  ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

This file is in my root directory,What is happening now is that all log levels are printed in my console.What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: I think you would have to instantiate your logger based on the env variable. So when the var is `error`, levels are only `error`.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: @caisah If I don't want to use the env. variable , Why are all log levels being printed when I'm only specifying the error level?

Comment: Are all the levels being printed or only the ones whose level is below `error` like `verbose`?

Comment: @JyotmanSingh Yes currently when I use logger.error or logger.info or logger.data all of these are printed.Am I doing anything wrong?                      I tried Adding the following line                                                                 if (process.env.node_env === "development") {
  myLogTransports.push(new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: "error",colorize: true }));
} but still I get all logs printed even though I specified in the node_env to only print "error" logs

Comment: Well I just tried your code and its working perfectly well for me. It prints `error` statement and does not print `info` statements.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh This is weird. Could you show me an example of how u run your code? When I specify "error", everything starting level "error" gets printed like debug,data and info!

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from my laptop right now. I'll post my working code in 2-3 hours. You also try posting your code where and how you're printing the log log statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137877/discussion-between-jyotman-singh-and-rawan-hamdi).